# Can't hide overflow-x in a media query

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, overflow

I have a header with menu, which is changed to burger menu when screen width is smaller than 650px. After that menu is positioned as absolute and translated to the right. When I click on burger menu it slides into view. Afterwards everything works, but I can't make overflow disappear.
I tried to experiment with adding overflow to different parent elements, but to no avail.

Here is the page - https://badgerwannabe.github.io/rocket-sockets/index.html
Here is a Github rep with files [enter link description here](https://github.com/badgerwannabe/rocket-sockets)

Would be grateful for any help.

UPD1: Steps to reproduce
Go to the website, open Dev Tools and resize the viewport to less that 650px of width, try to scroll to the right and you'll see the problem. Adding overflow to body at this media query does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `overflow: hidden` to the body element when you open the menu I think that's what you're looking for. If not, can you specify further what overflow you are trying to get rid of?

Edit: based on the comment, if you add `overflow-x: hidden` to the `body` tag, that should do it for you.

Comment: The problem is that overflow is there when the menu is not opened. If you go to the website, go to Dev Tools and resize the viewport to less that 650px of width, try to scroll to the right and you'll see the problem.

Adding overflow to body at this media query does not help.

Comment: Ah OK, I see the issue now. Let me take a look

Comment: I've updated the answer. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong - but adding "overflow-x: hidden" doesn't work neither at the top of the stylesheet, nor at 650px media query, I tried

Comment: That's strange as it's working for me when I'm testing. To help debug, can you update your site's Style with `body {overflow-x: hidden;}` at the top of the `650px` media query, verify it's not working as expected, and I can take a look?

Comment: I have updated,it as per your request you can take a look
https://badgerwannabe.github.io/rocket-sockets/index.html

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the confusion here but I don't see the issue anymore on the page. When it's under 650px I don't see the overflow to the right of the menu like I previously did. To help me understand what issue you're seeing can you possibly post a screenshot or gif of the issue? I'm looking in Chrome and Firefox on Mac, but I feel like I'm missing something as I don't see the issue anymore. What browser are you looking in?

Comment: It is not visible outright, but if you scroll to the right you will see it.
Here is my screenshot: https://ibb.co/cxsKPZK

Comment: Ah thanks! I can see the issue now. Didn't occur on multiple browsers, but does for Chrome device view and my mobile device. If you also add overflow-x hidden to the HTML element, ex: `html {overflow-x: hidden;}` at the 650px break point as well it should fix it

Comment: Wow, thanks man! I tried to put {overflow-x: hidden;} to body and to html separately, but never occurred to me that it might be fix putting both of them. Do you know the reason why this worked? Or it is just browser issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is happening because of the following elements.

```
...
<img class="background-line" alt="background-line" src="assets/images/Path 18.png">
...
<img id="mailbox-sm" src="assets/images/Mask Group 4.png" alt="small mailbox">
...
```

There are two options.

1. Add `overflow-x: hidden` to the `body` element.
2. Set the correct width to the above elements.

Comment: Hi there, thank your your input. "background-line" and "mailbox-sm" indeed produce overflow, but it is not that big as I have at the moment, it is definitely the menu.
Also, adding "overflow-x: hidden" to the body element does not help. neither at the top of style.css nor at 650px media query.

Answer (score 0):

When you translate the menu to the right (ie out of view) you could also set it

`display: none;`

setting it back to

`display: flex`

when you want it to slide into view.

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem, however it loses the animation of sliding into view. Do you know how can I show the animation keeping "display:none" fix?

The strange thing that for other people it works, i.e. pushing element out of the viewport and disabled overflow-x on the body.